# SQL trigger giving syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS demo_inc_when_viewstatus_one ;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  TRIGGER demo_inc_when_viewstatus_one AFTER UPDATE ON `tbl_ffa_demo`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE  `tbl_stats` SET open_demos=CASE WHEN NEW.demo_status=1  THEN 
 open_demos+1 , 
  total_demos=total_demos+1    WHERE  tbl_stats.area_id=NEW.territory  AND NEW.view_status=1
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

The error message I received was:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' total_demos=total_demos+1 WHERE tbl_stats.area_id=NEW.territory AND NE' at line 4

Comment: Did you simply neglect to tell what the actual error message was or is it classified?

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
  total_demos=total_demos+1    WHERE  tbl_stats.area_id=NEW.territory  AND NE' at line 4

Comment: Yes Exactly,But i couldn't figure out out what mistake i'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not follow the syntax for the case statement:

```
case when <condition> then <true branch> else <false branch> end
```

So, you should have something like:

```
...  SET open_demos=CASE WHEN NEW.demo_status=1
     THEN open_demos+1 ELSE open_demos=open_demos END, ...
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6

Comment: syntax error i've resolved by adding semicon after  update query but now there is an error of #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: I answered your question, you cannot expect **all** errors to be resolved in a single post!

Comment: Btw the last error message is quite explicit, it tells you **exactly** what is wrong. Pls interpret and act on it!